# Xamarin Can not compile using Android version 7

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-7.0-nougat

I Can not compile using Android version 7.
I want to get a plan for Android 7 in the 2015 Visual Studio.
I have installed sdk completely, installed Java Development Kit 1.8.0.92
But none of the above versions of Android 6 will be displayed for selection

[image]

Please give me a solution in this regard, thanks all

Comment: What version of `Xamarin.Android` do you have installed?

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, 

Xamarin for visual studio enterprise v4.0.1.145

Comment: Not Xamarin4VS, but the Xamarin.Andriod version

Comment: this version 4.6.2.7, and now update to 4.8

Comment: When in troubles with android sdk and stuff think about installing Android Studio, process all sdk, emulators and stuff installation from there, then use its setup paths from VS.

Comment: @HadiSalehy You need to upgrade to at least a `Xamarin.Android` 7.x version, `8.1.0-23` is the latest....

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your advice
I'm doing to update latest version
I hope my efforts will be fruitful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is on upgrading xamarin android
With the update, all versions of the api were finally made available
Thanks to the advice of all loved ones
[image]